Keyboard toolbar doesn't show up on second tab
In my iOS (18.1) application I need fields with non standard behavior and formatting to enter decimal numbers.
To achieve this, I decided to create a custom text field that utilizes the numeric keypad and toolbar with buttons for dismissing the keyboard and performing special operations.
Below is a simplified version of my implementation to highlight the issue I'm encountering.
struct MyField: View {
    @State private var label: String
    @State private var formatter: NumberFormatter
    @Binding private var value: Double?
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool

    init(label: String, value: Binding<Double?>, formatter: NumberFormatter) {
        self.label = label
        _value = value
        self.formatter = formatter
    }

    var body: some View {
        #if os(iOS)
            TextField(label, value: $value, formatter: formatter)
                .focused($isFocused)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                        if isFocused {
                            Spacer()
                            Button("-") {
                                if let value {
                                    self.value = -value
                                }
                            }
                            Button("Done") {
                                isFocused = false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        #endif
        #if os(macOS)
            TextField(label, text: $label, formatter: formatter)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
        #endif
    }
}

These custom fields are used in two different tabs. The issue is that the toolbar shows up only for the fields in the first tab but not for those in the second tab (note that the two tabs view are identical).
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Tab1()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab1", systemImage: "list.dash")
                }
            Tab2()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab2", systemImage: "list.dash")
                }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct Tab1: View {
    @State var text1: Double?
    @State var text2: Double?
    
    let nf: NumberFormatter = {
        let f = NumberFormatter()
        f.minimumFractionDigits = 3
        f.maximumFractionDigits = 3
        return f
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("First Tab")
            Form {
                MyField(label: "Number 1", value: $text1, formatter: nf)
                    .background(.green)
                MyField(label: "Number 2", value: $text2, formatter: nf)
                    .background(.cyan)
            }
            .formStyle(.columns)
            
            Text("Number 1: \(text1 ?? .nan)")
            Text("Number 2: \(text2 ?? .nan)")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


struct Tab2: View {
    @State var text1: Double?
    @State var text2: Double?
    
    let nf: NumberFormatter = {
        let f = NumberFormatter()
        f.minimumFractionDigits = 3
        f.maximumFractionDigits = 3
        return f
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Second Tab")
            Form {
                MyField(label: "Number 1", value: $text1, formatter: nf)
                MyField(label: "Number 2", value: $text2, formatter: nf)
            }
            .formStyle(.columns)
            
            Text("Number 1: \(text1 ?? .nan)")
            Text("Number 2: \(text2 ?? .nan)")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


Other answers suggest wrapping the field in a NavigationView:

    var body: some View {
        #if os(iOS)
            NavigationView {
                TextField(label, value: $value, formatter: formatter)
                    .focused($isFocused)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                            if isFocused {
                                Spacer()
                                Button("-") {
                                    if let value {
                                        self.value = -value
                                    }
                                }
                                Button("Done") {
                                    isFocused = false
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        #endif
        #if os(macOS)
            TextField(label, text: $label, formatter: formatter)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
        #endif
    }


This solution works, but it introduces several issues: the fields appear spaced out in the Form, exhibit strange behavior in the List, and prevent me from changing the background color.
Can anyone suggest a better approach that doesn't rely on using NavigationView?

As I try, Adding .tabViewStyle(.page) to TabView could resolve your problem

That works, but the TabView no longer displays the TabItems. Unfortunately, this makes it an unsuitable general solution.
